# Error while searching for a Pattern in the input using Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.5

I am trying to find out the number of patterns which are of form `1[0]1` in the input number. The pattern is, **there can be any number of zeros in between two 1's** as in, 893**10001**898.

I wrote a code to execute this in Python 3.5 using regular expression (**re**) which is as follows:

```
>>> import re

>>> input1 = 3787381001
>>> pattern = re.compile('[10*1]')

>>> pattern.search(input1)
```

But this throws me the following **error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
     pattern.match(input1)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Is there some workaround to clearly identify if the above pattern `1[0]1` is present in the input number?

Comment: Remove the square brackets and feed a string to the `re`, not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[10*1]` pattern matches a single char that is equal to a `1`, `0` or `*`. Also, a regex engine only looks for matches inside a text, it needs a string as the input argument.

Remove the square brackets and pass a string to the `re`, not an integer.

```
import re
input1 = '3787381001'
pattern = re.compile('10*1')
m = pattern.search(input1)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/B3veAv)

Note: if you need to get multiple occurrences, with overlapping matches (e.g. if you need to get `1001` and `10001` from `23100100013`), you need to use [`re.findall(r'(?=(10*1))', input1)`](https://ideone.com/ZfdLIP).